# Problems when loading sites

Tags: networking, linux-mint, internet

Something strange is happening with my pc. Most of the sites just doesn’t open with no reason. Browser each times just throws `Server not found`. After few second it works fine, then again not found. The problem also is in some other applications which uses internet connection (for example system update looses connection). To the router is also connected  several other computers that work without problems.

Here is an example:

```
kiril@kiril-X501A1 ~ $ ping github.com
ping: unknown host github.com
kiril@kiril-X501A1 ~ $ traceroute github.com
github.com: No address associated with hostname
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `github.com' on position 1 (argc 1)
kiril@kiril-X501A1 ~ $ traceroute facebook.com
traceroute to facebook.com (69.171.230.68), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  0.378 ms  0.580 ms  0.922 ms
 2  * * *
 3  81.7.67.65 (81.7.67.65)  3.846 ms  3.934 ms  3.794 ms
 4  82-135-180-4.static.zebra.lt (82.135.180.4)  6.851 ms 82-135-182-4.static.zebra.lt (82.135.182.4)  7.238 ms  6.699 ms
 5  80.249.209.115 (80.249.209.115)  39.536 ms  38.448 ms  39.025 ms
 6  ae1.bb02.ams2.tfbnw.net (31.13.29.90)  39.706 ms ae1.bb01.ams2.tfbnw.net (31.13.29.86)  37.793 ms ae1.bb02.ams2.tfbnw.net (31.13.29.90)  37.701 ms
 7  ae8.bb02.lhr2.tfbnw.net (74.119.76.65)  43.270 ms  42.563 ms ae4.bb02.bos2.tfbnw.net (204.15.23.199)  135.523 ms
 8  be14.bb01.ewr2.tfbnw.net (74.119.78.142)  129.109 ms  129.290 ms  130.037 ms
 9  be29.bb02.dca1.tfbnw.net (74.119.78.164)  133.867 ms be44.bb01.iad3.tfbnw.net (31.13.26.1)  142.009 ms ae15.bb04.dca1.tfbnw.net (74.119.76.26)  138.904 ms
10  be21.bb01.prn2.tfbnw.net (74.119.76.61)  209.282 ms ae28.bb03.prn2.tfbnw.net (31.13.25.149)  223.201 ms  213.090 ms
11  ae0.dr10.prn1.tfbnw.net (31.13.27.53)  208.828 ms ae44.dr05.prn2.tfbnw.net (31.13.27.13)  239.814 ms ae41.dr06.prn2.tfbnw.net (31.13.27.133)  207.633 ms
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  edge-star-mini-shv-17-prn1.facebook.com (69.171.230.68)  207.671 ms  201.389 ms  209.076 ms
kiril@kiril-X501A1 ~ $ traceroute github.com
github.com: No address associated with hostname
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `github.com' on position 1 (argc 1)
kiril@kiril-X501A1 ~ $ traceroute github.com
traceroute to github.com (192.30.252.131), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  0.353 ms  0.539 ms  0.884 ms
 2  * * *
 3  81.7.67.65 (81.7.67.65)  4.295 ms  4.256 ms  4.299 ms
 4  s-b6-link.telia.net (213.248.89.157)  26.201 ms  26.205 ms  26.803 ms
 5  * * *
 6  ae-4-90.edge3.Washington4.Level3.net (4.69.149.210)  143.054 ms ae-3-80.edge3.Washington4.Level3.net (4.69.149.146)  139.265 ms  139.305 ms
 7  ae-3-80.edge3.Washington4.Level3.net (4.69.149.146)  139.950 ms  139.889 ms ae-4-90.edge3.Washington4.Level3.net (4.69.149.210)  140.025 ms
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Also some info about OS:

```
kiril@kiril-X501A1 ~ $ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17
DISTRIB_CODENAME=qiana
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17 Qiana"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
cat: /etc/upstream-release: Is a directory
```

Popular sites which not found often: github, facebook, goole and etc. Some times it load some of the site and stops...

Comment: what is the content of your `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: is your machine connected to the router via cable or via wifi?

Comment: Would you open speedtest.net and tell us your speed?

Comment: @lese Tried wi-fi and cable - same. Also `kiril@kiril-X501A1 ~ $ sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search 212.59.2.2
`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro In most cases i get `latency test error`

Comment: Not good actually; that may explain why you do get DNS errors...communication problems. I see you are using the DNS servers from Lithuanian Telecom, it would be an interesting exercise to run your own and see if things improve; though if you are having that kind of problems they wont improve much.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro in our office also are few windows machines which are working perfectly so I think the problem is somewhere in my machine.

Comment: Which DNS servers are they using?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro default, which gives router.

Comment: try ethtool and do run an ethtool eth0.Try also to put in /etc/resolv.conf nameserver 8.8.8.8 and delete the rest to see if it makes a difference.